# \ubnldr.mbr missing or corrupt during Ubuntu 18.4 install

Tags: unetbootin

Im trying to install Ubuntu 18.4 on my Hp Notebook. I am on windows 10. Im using unetbootin to install the ubuntu 18.04 iso from my hard drive as i dont have a blank disc or usb. When i reboot and select unetbootin i get this error.
P.S i already disabled my secure boot.

File: \ubnldr.mbr
status: 0xc000007b
Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

Any idea how to fix this?